# angular.js:12477 SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

Tags: angularjs

Did search but cannot find solution yet.

### Environment:

angular 1.4.7
chrome 43.0.2357.124
ubuntu pc

### Problem:

myBoardStatus.html uses socket.io to talk with node.js server. 
When node.js server sees '/myBoardStatus', it `sendfile(path.resolve('../client/myBoardStatus.html')`.

myBoardStatus.html has this line

```
<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
```

Right now these 2 URL works fine, in chrome browser i can see messages from server once a while.

http://10.55.200.47:80/myBoardStatus

http://10.55.200.47:80/myBoardStatus.html

### But:

In my index.html, i have `<div ng-view></div>`.
It works fine for other pages through $routeProdiver, when i click buttons, the contents of this div gets updated.

So i added another button "myBoardStatus" trying to display messages from socket.io to this div.

http://10.55.200.47:80/#/5myBoardStatus

```
$routeProvider.when('/5myBoardStatus', {
    templateUrl: 'myBoardStatus.html'
    //redirectTo: '/myBoardStatus.html'
});
```

Got this:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
angular.js:12477 SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at eval (native)
    at http://10.55.200.47:80/3rdparty/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:2620
    at Function.m.extend.globalEval (http://10.55.200.47:80/3rdparty/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:2631)
    at m.fn.extend.domManip (http://10.55.200.47:80/3rdparty/jquery/jquery.min.js:3:23046)
    at m.fn.extend.append (http://10.55.200.47:80/3rdparty/jquery/jquery.min.js:3:20507)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://10.55.200.47:80/3rdparty/jquery/jquery.min.js:3:22055)
    at m.access (http://10.55.200.47:80/3rdparty/jquery/jquery.min.js:3:3286)
    at m.fn.extend.html (http://10.55.200.47:80/3rdparty/jquery/jquery.min.js:3:21623)
    at link (http://10.55.200.47:80/3rdparty/angular-1.4.7/angular-route.min.js:7:200)
    at aa (http://10.55.200.47:80/3rdparty/angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:73:90) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12477$get @ angular.js:9246aa @ angular.js:8791K @ angular.js:8289g @ angular.js:7680(anonymous function) @ angular.js:7555$get.g @ angular.js:7699r @ angular.js:8316x @ angular-route.js:935$get.n.$broadcast @ angular.js:16311(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:619(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14745$get.n.$eval @ angular.js:15989$get.n.$digest @ angular.js:15800$get.n.$apply @ angular.js:16097h @ angular.js:10546K @ angular.js:10744z.onload @ angular.js:10685

(The 1st line "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated" is warning)
```

If i use redirectTo instead of templateUrl, then nothing happens in the browser.

thanks for your help !